# React after Delete I get "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.state.products.filter is not a function"

Tags: reactjs

so after deleting I get "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.state.products.filter is not a function" error, but if I refresh item is deleted, maybe I did some simple mistake. so my delete method is:

```
deleteProduct(id) {
        ProductService.deleteProduct(id).then((res) => {
          this.setState({
            products: this.state.products.filter((p) => p.id !== id),
          });
        });
      }
```

Then I render data to state:

```
render() {
    const { data } = this.state.products;
    if (data) {
      return (
```

And I data.map like this:

```
{data.map((item) => (
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      class="btn btn-danger"
                      onClick={() => this.deleteProduct(item.id)}
                    >
                      Delete Product
                    </button>
              ))}
```

Comment: console.log your `this.state.products` in your `.then()` and check if it's actually an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` is not an object method. I'm guessing you're trying to update the data

you should be filtering data instead

```
ProductService.deleteProduct(id).then((res) => {
          const products = this.state.products;
          products.data.filter((p) => p.id !== id)
          this.setState({
            products: products,
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for answers that was a big help for me to move forward, because I realised that the problem was with my componentDidMount method:

```
componentDidMount() {
    ProductService.getProducts().then((response) => {
      this.setState({ products: response.data });
    });
  }
```

because for some reason if I do response.data it doesn't mount an array, but if I do just response, it mounts, but then delete method doesn't work, so maybe I need to go to look at React basic mounting. I tried to console.log(response.data) in my then() and I get array, but why not mounting I don't know, maybe some sort of beginner mistake as well.

Comment: my constructor looked like this: constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      products: [],
    };
    this.deleteProduct = this.deleteProduct.bind(this);
  }

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the *products* as an array to use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method. Here is an online [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-nightingale-sc4zm?file=/src/App.js)